# Zig zag straight lines bands from Quantum Espresso calculations

Tags: quantum-espresso, band-structure, electronic-structure

[image]During band structure calculations in Quantum espresso I found that the bands are coming in Linear form and not curvature. Why is this happening? Is there any explanation for this? Which parameters cause it and need correction?

Edit: I added a plot for reference.

Comment: You have to check the set of high symmetry points used (if they correspond to the cell used) and the defined path between them.

Comment: @Camps Sir, I am not talking about flat bands here. I am talking about bands coming in zig zag straight lines perpendicular to x axis. As I have understood that high symmetry points might cause this, I will check it out.

Comment: @epsilon02fft you should upload an image

Comment: It would be very helpful to see a plot of the bandstructure, but the most common case where this happens is when you accidentally calculate the states on a 3D k-point grid, instead of along a 1D k-point path. When you plot it, you'll just get the states at disconnected points in k-space, which your plotting program will join up with straight lines.

Comment: @PhilHasnip I have added the plot for reference. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Thanks for adding a plot. It looks to me like the k-points do not form a smooth 1D path through the Brillouin zone - could you put the k-point coordinates on the plot or, if not, in the question?